# Several Nt functions return STATUS_WAIT_0 on Windows 7 x32

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I have downloaded a Windows 7 x32 Enterprise (IE11) hyper-v image from Microsoft website to test a research project.

For some reason all the Ntdll functions I call (syscall) return STATUS_WAIT_0. I mean all of them that I have tested including RtlGetVersion, NtAllocateVirtualMemory, NtCreateFile and more.

Could this be because it's a virtual machine ? Or could it be because I do direct system calls ?

Please advise, I have tested my project under non-virtual machines including latest Windows 10 and it works fine so I doubt it's my code.

**Update:**

STATUS_WAIT_0 can be considered as STATUS_SUCCESS since it's value is both 0.

Comment: `STATUS_WAIT_0 == 0 == STATUS_SUCCESS`

Comment: @RbMm Yes that is how it's defined, but why ? Makes no sense on some OS to return STATUS_SUCCESS and on some STATUS_WAIT_0...

Comment: strange question. OS return binary value - 0. 0 is 0. everywhere. `STATUS_SUCCESS` or `STATUS_WAIT_0` of say `S_OK` or `NOERROR` or `false` - all is only interpretation of 0.

Comment: @RbMm Ok I understand, of course 0 is 0. I was just confused why on this specific OS the status description is STATUS_WAIT_0. Honestly was thinking it's because I do direct system call. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly you still not understand. api call not return string. it return 0. who and how convert 0 to string ? and this is of course not OS specific and not because you do direct system call

Comment: @RbMm Maybe I rushed in explaining how I got the "string" value. Calling FormatMessageW with param FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM and passing NTSTATUS as error code will return the "string" representation from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55 Of course I do not check this, I check return value, but was very confused why that "string" is different.

Comment: *Calling FormatMessageW with param FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM and passing NTSTATUS* is **error** you need call `FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE, GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"), status,..`

Comment: @RbMm Yes... I did not want to post full call, you got the idea. (FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE|FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll"),code, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT))...

Comment: `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` - error. this is mutually exclusive

Comment: @RbMm Well... my mistake then

Comment: Please post as an answer instead to add in the question, and feel free to mark it to make it clear, Thanks.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Thanks for the info, but I believe you would be more suitable to submit such answer since you work for Microsoft ? :) After all, what do we peasants know about windows and NT functions... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ntdll function basically returns a `NTSTATUS`, like [`RtlGetVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlgetversion),[`NtAllocateVirtualMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntallocatevirtualmemory),[`NtCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntcreatefile) and more.

The following document contains the common usage details of the `NTSTATUS` values
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55

**Return value/code:**

0x00000000

`STATUS_SUCCESS`/`STATUS_WAIT_0`

**Description:**

The operation completed successfully.

The caller specified WaitAny for WaitType and one of the dispatcher objects in the Object array has been set to the signaled state.

Comment: Hi, @Norbert Boros, If this answer does help you, please feel free to mark it for the people with the same issue.